# How to print a set of asterisk(*) towers on the same line, sorted by height in Java?

Tags: java

The code below is the closest iteration of my project that I've been able to get.
The goal of the program is to print the towers side by side from tallest on the left to the shortest on the right.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: So you're having trouble printing all three towers at the same time? You just need to start with the tallest tower, then when you reach the height of the second tower (while going down printing the first tower) you start printing the second tower, and then do the same for the third tower as you did with the second. That's basically what your professor's  psuedocode is doing.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, nothing is keeping the highest tower on the left. Do the heights have to be random?

Comment: I guess my real question is how would i go about printing the tower all on the same line with the given input? @shmosel

Comment: You are correct, it is not stated that the towers are needed to be displayed in that order @cricket_007

Comment: @Raptor6872 So, does my answer below solve your problem?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, thank you for the help! I was able to understand and implement the logic and statements that you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is your homework, the main implementation details are up to you, but I'd suggest breaking this down into some methods.

`getFloor` - prints `width` many `c` chars followed by a space.

```
private static void printFloor(int width, char c) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
    sb.append(" ");
    System.out.print(sb.toString());
}
```

Then, that psudeocode translates into this

```
// For each row=maxHeight ... 1
for (int height = maxHeight; height >= 0; --height) {
    printFloor(w0, '*'); // print width many chars

    if (tower1 >= height) { // if tower1 is at height row
        printFloor(w1, '*');
    } else {
        printFloor(w1, ' ');
    }

    if (tower2 >= height) { // if tower2 is at height row
        printFloor(w2, '*');
    } else {
        printFloor(w2, ' ');
    }

    System.out.println(); // Start next height
}
```

You need to figure out how to get `int maxHeight = max(tower0, tower1, tower2)`. As well as sort that into descending order.

Your code should get already get you the widths `(w0, w1, w2)`.

Comment: No need to post your solution. (And that might be against your academic policy if you did)